# Automating update-database command

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I find myself running these command through Package Mnager Console frequently:

```
Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName CartConfiguration -Verbose

Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName IdentityConfiguration -Verbose

Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName ShopConfiguration -Verbose
```

Is there a way to automate these by adding a script file to the solution and execute that script (containing the lines above) through `PowerShell` or the `Package Manager Console` itself ?

Comment: What was your solution?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is by using the Migrate.exe that is given with Entity Framework.

Once you have migrate.exe, copy it to the location of the assembly that contains your migrations.

Then simply add a PostBuild step to your project, and run the Migrate.exe tool via the script.

I have not used it with ConfigurationTypeName, but I imagine it would be something like:

```
Migrate.exe whereYourMigrationsAre.dll CartConfiguration/startupConfigurationFile=”MyApp.exe.config”
```

Documentation on the exe can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj618307.aspx